# If $\alpha= (1+\sqrt{-19})/2$ then any ring homomorphism $f : \mathbb{Z}[\alpha] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_3$ is the zero map

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

This is from a past qualifying exam.

Here is the question:

> If $\alpha= (1+\sqrt{-19})/2$ then any ring homomorphism $f : \mathbb{Z}[\alpha] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_3$ is the zero map.

Here is what I thought of: $\mathbb{Z}_3$ is a field. So I was thinking of using something like $ \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]/(f(\alpha))$ is isomorphic to the field $\mathbb{Z}_3$. If I can somehow show that $f(\alpha)$ is the root of some irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Z_3}$ then I will have what I want? I also 
have that $\alpha(1-\alpha)=5$. So If I apply $f$ to this relation and then using the fact that $f$ is ring homomorphism I get $f(\alpha)\cdot (f(1)-f(\alpha))=f(5)$. I also know that $f(1)=1$. How do I proceed from here? Am I on the right track?

Can anybody please help me on this? Your time and answers are always appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no *unitary* homomorphism as specified, i.e. carrying the multiplicative element of the one ring to that of the other. So the only homomorphism is the *zero* morphism, that takes everything in the domain to *zero*. You were trying to show that the map was onto, but it can’t be. Look at the whole situation again.

Comment: If you ever get around to studying algebraic number theory, you can reanswer this question as follows. The kernel of $f$ would have to be an ideal of index $3$. And there aren't any 'cause three is inert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using @Lubin's hint.
Discuss what $f(\alpha)$ would be? If $f(1)=1$,then

1. $f(\alpha)=0$? then  $f(\alpha)(f(1)-f(\alpha))=f(5)$, so $0\cdot(1-0)=5=2$ !?
2. $f(\alpha)=1$? then  $1\cdot(1-1)=5$ !?
3. $f(\alpha)=2$? then  $2\cdot(1-2)=5$ !?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But should it be $f(5)$ and not $5$ in your computations above??. Why would $f(5)=2$?

Comment: What is your $\mathbb{Z}_3$? Is $5=2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_3$?. $f(5)=f(4+1)=f(4)+f(1)=f(3+1)+f(1)=\cdots=f(1)+f(1)+f(1)+f(1)+f(1)=5f(1)=5$.

Comment: Oh I got it :-). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\,\alpha\,$ is a root of $\,g(x) =  x^2-x+5\,$ so its image is a root in $\,\Bbb Z_3,\,$ contra $\,g\,$ has no roots $\in \Bbb Z_3.$